# Unable to delete post in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Unable to delete the post in rails, whenever i click on the delete button it does nothing, it doesn't even show the confirmation message nor any error. How should i fix this problem? should i provide more details other than the details stated below?

posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

 def index
    @posts =Post.all

 end

 def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
 end


 def new
   @post= Post.new
 end

 def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.save
    redirect_to @post
 end

 def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
 end

 def update
    @post= Post.find(params[:id])
    if(@post.update(post_params))
        redirect_to @post
    else
        render'edit'
    end

 end

 def destroy
    @post= Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy

    redirect_to posts_path
 end



 private def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:Name, :Country, :Details)
 end

 end
```

show.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(@post), :class => 'btn btn-default' %>
<%= link_to "Delete", post_path(@post), 
                    method: :delete,
                    data: {confirm:'Are you Sure?'},
                    :class => 'btn btn-danger' %>
```

edit.html.erb

```
<h1>Edit Vacation</h1>

<%= form_for :post, url: post_path(@post), method: :patch  do |f| %>

<p>
<%= f.label :Name %><br>
<%= f.text_field( :Name, {:class=> 'form-control'} )%>
</p>

<p>
<%=f.label :Country %><br>
<%= f.text_field( :Country, {:class=> 'form-control'}) %>
</p>

<p>
<%=f.label :Details %><br>
<%= f.text_area( :Details, {:class=> 'form-control'}) %>
</p>

 <p>
 <%= f.submit({:class => 'btn btn-primary'}) %>
 </p>
 <% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
# For details on the DSL available within this file, see 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

root 'posts#index'

resources :posts

end
```

application.js

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which 
   will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, 
or any plugin's
// vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a 
relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear 
at the bottom of the
// compiled file. JavaScript code in this file should be added after the 
last require_* statement.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-
directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
= require rails-ujs
= require turbolinks
= require_tree .
```

Comment: you have restarted the server and still it does not work rite?

Comment: How does the request in your log file look like? How does your `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` look like? Do you have that JavaScript file included into your layout file?

Comment: @spickermann I've added the application.js information above, i uncomment those `require`, because previously was giving me error like `Object doesn't support this property or method`

Comment: You can check for errors by this simple statement- `puts @post.errors.messages` and see the terminal for its output just write it below your `@post.destroy` in `destroy` action of your controller.

Answer (score -1):

In your controller:

```
def destroy
    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to postss_url, notice: 'post was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
end
```

Answer (score -2):

I've solve this problem by commenting back those `require` in application.js and then added `gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'` in gem file after that run `bundle update coffee-script-source` and restart the server thus i was able to delete the post